# sum on date of the month

Tags: date, sum

I have daily data for a year:

```
25-Apr-17   45
26-Apr-17   50
27-Apr-17   53
28-Apr-17   47
29-Apr-17   34
30-Apr-17   66
01-May-17   10
02-May-17   42
03-May-17   22
04-May-17   65
05-May-17   76
06-May-17   35
```

I would like to sum the value, at the month of given date, but prior of the given date ie:

```
month sum as of date    03-May-17;
```

I would need to get `10+42+22 = 72` only. 
While `04-May-17` value onwards should not be included in sum.

I have tried with sumproduct, sumif but none seems to match this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this in excel or google sheets.

If you put your dates in col A, values in col B and your criteria date in E1.

Put this formula in another cell (not in col A or B)

`=arrayformula(SUM(IF(DAY(A:A)<=DAY($E$1),IF(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH($E$1),B:B,0),0)))`

Oddly enough I couldn't do `=IF(AND([range of values and compare],[range of values and compare]))`

Which would be cleaner but it seemed to evaluate as false